# Mule ESB LDAP connector able to bind but fails at lookup

Tags: java, xml, ldap, mule

So I am trying to create a Mule flow to authenticate against my LDAP. I want to bind sending a JSON in through PHP then check if it binds. It then returns the value of the binded user so I can store that in my session variable.

Sending the JSON works well and I can authenticate to the server as I have tried with wrong password and it doesn't work. It binds successfully but cannot do the lookup after that. I hope someone can help.

Here's my code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json" xmlns:ldap="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ldap" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.6.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ldap http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ldap/current/mule-ldap.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="localhost" port="8080" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <ldap:config name="ldapConf" url="ldap://address.address.address:389/" doc:name="LDAP">
        <ldap:connection-pooling-profile evictionCheckIntervalMillis="1" minEvictionMillis="1" exhaustedAction="WHEN_EXHAUSTED_WAIT"/>
    </ldap:config>  
    <flow name="loginldapFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/login" doc:name="HTTP">
            <http:response-builder>
                <http:header headerName="content-type" value="text/plain"/>
            </http:response-builder>
        </http:listener>
        <json:json-to-object-transformer doc:name="JSON to Object" returnClass="java.util.Map"/>
        <ldap:bind config-ref="ldapConf" authDn="#[payload.username]@address.addresss" authPassword="#[payload.password]" authentication="simple" doc:name="LDAP"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Here's the error :

```
INFO  2015-05-07 14:01:05,452 [[loginldap].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01] org.mule.module.ldap.api.jndi.LDAPJNDIConnection: Binded to ldap://address.address.address:389/ with simple authentication as Mule1@address.address
INFO  2015-05-07 14:01:05,452 [[loginldap].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01] org.mule.module.ldap.api.jndi.LDAPJNDIConnection: Already binded to ldap://address.address.address:389/ with simple authentication as Mule1@address.address. Closing connection first.
INFO  2015-05-07 14:01:05,452 [[loginldap].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01] org.mule.module.ldap.api.jndi.LDAPJNDIConnection: Connection Mule1@address.address@ldap://address.address.address:389/ closed.
INFO  2015-05-07 14:01:05,467 [[loginldap].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01] org.mule.module.ldap.api.jndi.LDAPJNDIConnection: Re-binding to ldap://address.address.address:389/ with simple authentication as Mule1@address.address
INFO  2015-05-07 14:01:05,468 [[loginldap].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01] org.mule.module.ldap.api.jndi.LDAPJNDIConnection: Binded to ldap://address.address.address:389/ with simple authentication as Mule1@address.address
INFO  2015-05-07 14:01:05,468 [[loginldap].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01] org.mule.module.ldap.adapters.LDAPConnectorConnectionIdentifierAdapter: Bind was successful for user: Mule1@address.address
WARN  2015-05-07 14:01:05,468 [[loginldap].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01] org.mule.module.ldap.api.jndi.LDAPJNDIConnection: Lookup failed.
WARN  2015-05-07 14:01:05,468 [[loginldap].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01] org.mule.module.ldap.adapters.LDAPConnectorConnectionIdentifierAdapter: Cannot retrieve entry for dn: Mule1@address.address
org.mule.module.ldap.api.InvalidAttributeException: Mule1@address.address: [LDAP: error code 34 - 0000208F: NameErr: DSID-03100225, problem 2006 (BAD_NAME), data 8350, best match of:
    'Mule1@address.address'

Caused by: javax.naming.InvalidNameException: Mule1@address.address: [LDAP: error code 34 - 0000208F: NameErr: DSID-03100225, problem 2006 (BAD_NAME), data 8350, best match of:
    'Mule1@address.address'
```

I've looked at what error 34 is but I cannot add DN to bind in Mule.

I have also tried to remove the connection pooling profile and other configurations with the same result.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error is that the DN is invalid. Look at the answers at this previous question: [javax.naming.InvalidNameException: [LDAP: error code 34 - invalid DN]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18832031/javax-naming-invalidnameexception-ldap-error-code-34-invalid-dn).

You could try using a tool to explore the LDAP structure like http://jxplorer.org/ to understand what the server is expecting.

Comment: Yes I know this is the error but I don't know how to fix it. I tried adding dn after the url but I get the same error. If I try to add in authDn I'm not even able to bind

Comment: I edited my answer to suggest using a tool to explore the server structure.